# Increasing Assembly revision in Every build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

A few days back I visited a company with a fairly small dev team.

They Use VS2019 and mostly Web Form Apps. I found their policy of increasing Assembly and
file versions revision by one on every single build questionable.

Even if nothing is changed they increase the revision on every build.(they put a * for revision in Assemblyinfo.cs)

I want to know if the above procedure can cause any issues whatsoever? For example I remember  the old versions of VS had a limit for the number of revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exact scenario is actually addressed in the [Visual Studio docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/general/assembly-version-assembly-file-version#attributes-in-assemblyinfocs)

> ```cs
> // Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
> // Major Version
> // Minor Version
> // Build Number
> // Revision
> [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]  
> [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
> ```
>
> Providing a (*) in place of absolute number makes compiler increase the number by one every time you build.
>
> Suppose you're building a framework assembly for your project that is used by lot of developers while building the application assemblies. If you release new version of assembly frequently, say once every day, and if assemblies are strong named, Developers will have to change the reference every time you release new assembly. It can be cumbersome and may lead to wrong references also. A better option in such closed group and volatile scenarios would be to fix the `AssemblyVersion` and change only the `AssemblyFileVersion`. Use the assembly file version number to communicate the latest release of assembly. In this case, developers won't have to change the references and they can overwrite the assembly in reference path. In central or final release builds it makes more sense to change the `AssemblyVersion` and most keep the `AssemblyFileVersion` same as assembly version.

Comment: Understood, But how about the case I stop the code, don't do any changes, and then run the code and new version gets created? so these revisions are not anything but just re-run and compile of the code.

Comment: The question is if every single revision need to have an explanation/season attached to it?

Comment: In general using the build number to increment the semantic version is for *CI builds* not for *dev builds*. When you have a binary built by a CI system it is helpful to have a unique ID for every artifact produced, so you can trace back if some particular error happens. For a personal dev build it is meaningless to increment the assembly version, since official builds shouldn't be produced by individual devs anyway

Comment: That's exactly what happens in the small company I mentioned.  Every dev build creates a new revision number. So I guess based on your comments this will be harmless if not useful.